# Excel SUM() Formula Not Working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a complex formula: two SUMIFS formula nested in a SUM formula. The concept is to sum amounts given a specific time period and specific account code.
This formula seems to work great. I get an amount of 4119.20 for one account, and -4119.20 for the other account. My other SUM formula, which is supposed to total the group, should be 0, but instead reads "9.09495E-13".

I have six accounts in the group and one of them that is "0" appears to give this "9.09495e-13". there are no transactions under this account at all.

Furthermore, I tried deleting the formula and just putting in "0", but this also resulted in a sum of the group of "9.0495e-13"

I realize that this is vague, but I'm hoping someone else ran into a similar problem.

EDIT 18-07-18-2221:
[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: you're much more likely to get a good response if you can create a simple example that others can reproduce.. e.g. a simple example needn't involve an 'account number'.  Or i'm sure you can use the same formulae but different data.. or the same concept behind the formulae.  Or troubleshoot, look at the values of smaller parts of the formula and see if they're right,  or of smaller sections of the data

Comment: I hear you, but that's not possible. The problem has nothing to do with account numbers. Maybe I'm wordy. The SUM formula isn't adding correctly. I will post an image to show you.

Comment: Perhaps it might help if you show what you mean by nested SUMIFs in a SUM formula?

Comment: maybe you know but that number sounds like a tiny number that might be getting rounded to 0. Are you saying you tried making J17=0  ?

Comment: Also why can't you make a new spreadsheet, with just the relevant column.. and see if you still have the problem?  it's simplifying it as a way of troubleshooting

Comment: another thing to consider, is if the formatting of the cells is different, such that one of them gets rounded to 0, and the other has the exponentially small number.

Comment: The value you're getting is 0.0000000000009 if I counted the zeros right.  That's internal rounding error that happens when you try to work with fractional numbers as binary.  You see it only because the cell is using a generic format.  If you format it as a number and specify 2 decimal places for cents, or use an accounting format, it will disappear when the value is displayed rounded to a "normal" number.  But be aware that internal rounding error like that can cause "exact match" or "exactly equal" tests to return a wrong result.

Comment: @NickFleetwood, better edit the question and include the formula you have tried so far will help us to fix the issue since we get cell reference !

Comment: some of you clearly didn't view the image, or you would know that the formula is "=SUM(J12:J17)" , and that J17 is the problem even though it is "0"...

Comment: @NickFleetwood  Why are you talking about some kind of mythical nested "sumif" when you say yourself the formula is `=SUM(J12:J17)` there is no IF or SUMIF there.

Comment: @barlop As I have clearly showed in the image, the value of J17 is "0". I typed it in. No formula. I did this only to troubleshoot. I was trying to provide background if mentioning the =SUMIF formula. I apologize if that was confusing. However, when adding J17 using =SUM, Excel calculates 9.0495e-13. I don't know why it does that, but that's why I put up an image to show you that. Sir Adelaide provided a specific solution that solved the problem, but didn't answer the question. So my question is still the same: why "9.0495e-13" is equal to "0".

Comment: @barlop you clearly missed reading in elementary school. J17 = 0. no rounding. no formula. just 0. typed in. but when summed, it equals to 9.0495e-13. that is still the question. ok whatever dude. im done.

Comment: @NickFleetwood  It is you that wrote to adelaide saying  `" I am confused on why "9.0495e-13" is equal to "0" `    You didn't ask him about J17 in that statement. You asked him a question that is like asking why 3 equals 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were expecting `0.0` but got `9.0495e-13`

`9.0495e-13` is `0.0`, you just need to change the format. Select the cell then click this button on the task bar:

[image]

Comment: effing perfect. thank you sir. I am confused on why "9.0495e-13" is equal to "0". I mean, I literally typed in "0", no formula or anything.

Comment: @NickFleetwood "9.0495e-13" is NOT equal to "0"     I already told you the following before this answer was posted, "another thing to consider, is if the formatting of the cells is different, such that one of them gets rounded to 0, and the other has the exponentially small number. "    So it is a very small number getting rounded to 0 because of your formatting. As I said in that comment.

Comment: @NickFleetwood There is actually more than one comment that explain to you that it is a tiny number being rounded to 0.   I think that is pretty clear and no reason for you to be confused and still believing that one number equals a different number, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

What you've stumbled upon is a variant of one of the first things taught in computer science. This is basically a floating point overflow error (“rounding error” in layman’s terms).

In Excel, try

```
=SUM(A1:A4)
```

with:

```
A1   10^20
A2   1
A3  -10^20
A4  -1
```

Clearly we'd expect the answer to be `0`. Excel will give it as `-1`. 
You can also try `=A1+A2+A3+A4`. The answer is `-1` again. Now try `=A1+A3+A2+A4` in that order. Excel will now give the correct answer of `0`.

Because of the way Excel stores numbers (IEEE 754), if you try to add a number vastly smaller to another it will discard it and hence the errors. 
In the above example, `10^20`+`1` yields `10^20`. 
As such it is good practice to add numbers of a similar magnitude together first.

In your example, there is likely also a rounding error issue arising from not being able to represent 4119.2 exactly in binary.

For the above reasons, programmers and engineers will prefer to store number as whole numbers (integers) rather than floating point numbers (non whole numbers) where such accuracy matters. For example, financial systems have strict rules on only calculating with whole numbers (for example cents and not dollars and cents). Similarly, time is stored as seconds from a fixed date. The classic example of this going wrong is the Patriot missile failure in the first Gulf War killing 28 people – the error of 0.000000095 of a second added enough times mixed with the high velocity of a Scud was enough for the Patriot anti-missile system to discard the Scud as an anomaly.

In your case, for all intents and purposes, 9x10^-13 is 0 (as others have pointed out)!

If you are interested in this further, these [first year notes are pretty accessible](http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf).

Some info about the [Patriot missile failure](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html).

Comment: +1 for the "computational mechanics" part. Keep it up. \(^_^)