# A value in Excel that is equal but different

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have a cell `A1` with formula `=1/(1/(1/(1.6-1)-1)-1)`. The result shows as `2`, which is mathematically correct. But I am aware of the virtues of floating point representation...

Now when I check whether the cell's value is *equal* to `2` (`=A1=2`), I get `TRUE`. And `<` gives `FALSE`. But when I *subtract* `2` (`=A1-2`), I get `-1.77635683940025E-15` (`-2^-49`), so it must be *less* than `2`!

A screenshot (with Dutch decimal separators and dark mode):

[image: screenshot]

I would expect these checks to agree. Why don't they? Is it because the difference is [denormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)?

Is this a bug or a feature? I found [some documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) but AFAICT it does not explain this inconsistency.

I'm using Microsoft Excel 365 MSO (16.0.13001.20338) 64-bit. My file can be [downloaded from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmmTR85uFLjo2eaOZ68JRLFYN9_7_v6X). Google does show a 0 by the way.

Comment: I don't get that outcome when replicating your issue

Comment: 2016 with office 365, I tried subtracting 2 in the formula =1/(1/(1/(1.6-1)-1)-1)-2, then also by doing A1-2 etc, each time it resulted in 0, I changed number formats also. Add some images to the question showing the inputs outputs etc. also have you tried using `evaluate formula' on the formulas task bar ?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with 2016

Comment: @PeterH it has to be a cell on its own, then check in a different one. Added screenshot, great suggestion!

Comment: I reproduced this issue in build 16.0.13001.20384 (64-bit).

Comment: Now I'm wondering why I CAN'T reproduce this when others can :S

Comment: I ran into a similar issue in the past. The answer that seemed to explain this best was "This is basically a floating point overflow error", but you did reference this before. I would argue my problem was worse in that I was running into this error when TYPING 0, no calculation. My solution was to use ROUND function, but I don't think you are interested. My question is here: https://superuser.com/questions/1341370/excel-sum-formula-not-working

Answer (score 1):

> I found some documentation but AFAICT it does not explain this inconsistency.

I think it's covered by "Example: Adding a negative number":

- 43.1-43.2 = -0.1 - it already can't be stored correctly, but it's still displayed correctly, same as your A1, it's not exactly 2, but behaves as 2
- when you add 1 on Microsoft example, or subtract 2 in your example, the error became apparent

The key here is that Excel stores digital numbers and not decimals. 52 bits is slightly more precise than 15 decimal digits, when the difference is smaller than 10^-15 it might still be stored but it's rounded in all times it's displayed or compared, however cause difference in calculations.

> But this does not explain why Excel thinks =2 is TRUE

When you ask Excel to compare 2 (decimal) to the value in A1 (already stored as binary), first it needs to convert one of the numbers. It converts A1 to decimal, which **is exactly 2** with 15 decimal precision. (why it conveys to decimal for comparison is indeed not documented and I don't know the reason for that)

Comment: Excel is as precise as it can be and I think the documentation link shows that Microsoft is very much aware of (what you call) 'unpredictability' of denormals. I just wonder whether the behavior I found is 'by design' or an oversight...

Comment: I understand the value displayed is inexact. But this does not explain why Excel thinks `=2` is `TRUE`.